# Content display errors - Missing styling and content

Tags: nodes

I have a local Drupal 7.2.6 installation that I am experiencing a strange issue with.  If I log in and go to Find Content the it displays my content as expected.  Clicking on an item takes me to the relevant page and everything looks ok,

However a few of the content items take me to a page that looks like this....
[image]

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: It's obviously looking like some or all of your css files aren't be loaded.  You could try clearing caches but that's just a shot in the dark.  Without any further information or details, I'm afraid that's about as much as can be expected as to an answer.

Comment: Could you tell us which theme and Drupal version are you using? Did you recently added/modified a hook preprocess for theme, node or the page?

Comment: I have updated the original post with the version number 7.2.6,  I am using a custom theme that I am trying to get working

Comment: The only common thing with the content that is exhibiting this problem is that they are all unpublished, don't know if that helps at all?

Comment: Some more information, looking at firebugs console output I can see "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: ^^if they are unpublished, do you see the same behavior as a regular user as well as the admin; eg, this is sounding now like a permissions issue.

Comment: So what's exactly a problem with your display? Display like display... What are you asking? Unless you want so me CSS to be there, but in that case you should describe with more detail what CSS files you expected, what was their HTTP status, is there something in error.log or watchdog, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be related to a PHP error, see which are the the resources (images, css, js, ...) that are returning 500 HTTP error.

Check if the issue only happens with a specific content type.

Check the Drupal log (admin/reports/dblog) and the Apache log to find more info about this issue.